# What is the benefit of using Polymorphism in c++ on simple example?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have simple programm that shows a polymorphism. The question: WHAT IS THE BENFIT OF USING bs->test() above simple call of dr1.test() and dr2.test()?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
public:
    virtual void test()=0;
};
class derieved1:public base
{
public:
    void test(){cout<<"Derieved 1"<<endl;}
};
class derieved2:public base
{
public:
    void test(){cout<<"Derieved 2"<<endl;}
};
int main()
{   
    derieved1 dr1;
    derieved2 dr2;
    base* bs;
    bs=&dr1;bs->test();
    bs=&dr2;bs->test();
    dr1.test();
    dr2.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Are you asking what the benefit of polymorphism is? (just want to double-check)

Comment: On this simple example.This was a question on interview on c++ programmer, what is the benefit of using bs->test(), because we just can make a call of funtions dr1.test(), dr2.test()? Is there any difference?

Comment: How can we tell you the benefit that polymorphism provides for a useless piece of code?

Comment: You're presupposing that polymorphism is beneficial, either here or in general; who says that supposition is valid?

Comment: This was a perfect question. Anybody start learning C++ can have this question. It is not vague. It is a clear, precise one. In fact, it defies each word in the sentence "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form". I never have understood the SO practice of downplaying genuine questions just because of they question the 'established' knowledge (of a few)....terrible...

Answer (score 3):

In your example, there is no added value in using polymorphism.  Polymorphism adds value in cases where you don't know anymore what the derived class is.

e.g.:

```
void testFunction(base* tester)
{
  tester->test();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Of course, there is one added value: showing that polymorphism really works.

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough this seems a silly question, I have heard this question multiple times from newbies and this is a real doubt for anybody who learns oop in the beginning. 
Of course, you are right in that example. But, **in real world you are not writing all programs on a single page** !! So, it helps when you have some complex logic which can be split into something you know and something you don't know. **You can code what you know** and **give hooks** for others to fill in what you don't know, but what they know.

Consider the example of a travel agency, they don't know how bus companies and train operators schedule and run their services. But, they know how to get the best deal out of different types of operators (but, remember that they all are bus/train operators). So, **they just need a contract** (equivalent to your base class) by which they know how to get a schedule for a given date from each bus/train operator (i.e, I want the possible schedule for so and so date for so and so destinations). As long as all operators adhere to this contract, the travel agency can do what they know best. i.e, Get all these possible schedules and choose the best out for their clients. Choosing the best is the travel agency's task. They don't have to care how the bus/train operators internally maintains the schedules/costs etc (which is the derived class implementation). Since the travel agency is only working with the contracts with the bus/train operators, later if a new bus/train operator comes, the travel agency's logic need not be modified (Consider your question, if you use d1.test() and dr2.test() if a new DerivedClass3 is added, shouldn't you change your code to handle this case?).

You will see these kind of patterns in every walk of life. You know the contract for eating out. Look into menu, order the food, pay and come back (base class methods). No need to know how they cook, how they make menu etc.

So, in short polymorphism helps you to implement situations where you can implement one part of the program independently without knowing the inner details of the dependent implementations, but only by knowing the interfaces.

So, in your example, you could implement a complex algorithm or logic just using the base class without caring about which derived classes are there. The users of your algorithm could add various instances of different types of derived classes and still your algorithm would work.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

**On this particular case** there *can* be a disadvantage to using polymorphism. Calling `dr1.test()` will be resolved statically, while calling it through a base pointer *can* resolve the call dynamically, so some overhead can occur. (I'm saying "can" because the compiler could optimize this).

Answer (score 0):

There often is no benefit to polymorphism.  Except as an experiment like yours, one probably should avoid polymorphism unless one finds a definite reason to use it.

However, definite reasons to use polymorphism do arise.  Most such reasons are notoriously hard to explain adequately in a few paragraphs -- and notoriously poorly explained in far too many programming books.  Examples given in such books regrettably tend to be contrived to the point of utter uselessness -- yet this isn't wholly the books' fault.

A container (like a list or a vector) of *pointers to* objects is probably the most typical case for polymorphism.  When one part of your code must register an object for later use by another part of your code, and the object has not only distinct data but distinct behavior, then polymorphism is likely to help.

One of the most useful features of polymorphism lies in how it supports the addition of new types to existing code, types not foreseen at the time the original code was designed.  Thus, polymorphism may often be more a matter of maintenence practice than of logical conception.

In many substantial programs, polymorphism is not needed at all, and in programs of less than 2000 lines it seldom is needed or helpful.  Polymorphism addresses a practical design problem that tends to arise in programs 10,000 lines or longer -- which is precisely why the examples typically given of polymorphism tend to be so uselessly contrived.  It really is hard to see the need for polymorphism until one has written a program big enough for it.